# How does serial driver get attached to a tty port

Tags: linux, drivers, tty

I am looking at Linus sample UART driver code here

https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3/blob/master/tty/tiny_serial.c

Below is snipped from the code where UART driver is sending data to the tty port

```
static void tiny_timer(unsigned long data)
{
    struct uart_port *port;
    struct tty_struct *tty;
    struct tty_port *tty_port;


    port = (struct uart_port *)data;
    if (!port)
        return;
    if (!port->state)
        return;
    tty = port->state->port.tty;
    if (!tty)
        return;

    tty_port = tty->port;

    /* add one character to the tty port */
    /* this doesn't actually push the data through unless tty->low_latency is set */
    tty_insert_flip_char(tty_port, TINY_DATA_CHARACTER, 0);

    tty_flip_buffer_push(tty_port);

    /* resubmit the timer again */
    timer->expires = jiffies + DELAY_TIME;
    add_timer(timer);

    /* see if we have any data to transmit */
    tiny_tx_chars(port);
}
```

However, what I am not clear about, looking at the code, is how is the coupling between UART port and tty port ever established. Is that something that has to be configured manually in Linux?

Comment: @jsotola. Thanks for getting back. I went through all of tiny_serial.c once again. And not sure if we are on the same page here. I know  where the data from serial driver gets sent to tty. tty_port = tty->port; tty_insert_flip_char(tty_port, TINY_DATA_CHARACTER, 0), But how does the uart port even get paired up with the tty port in the first place. that is what I don't understand. 
 tty = port->state->port.tty;
So in this line, uart port seems to have been magically populated with tty port.

Comment: @jsotola Ah. Are you referring to the driver not being hardware backed? I know that this is not hardware backed. My question was how does the serial port struct get populated with tty port struct. That is what I meant by "coupling" . Serial driver is downstream of tty driver. See the 3rd slide here https://bootlin.com/doc/legacy/serial-drivers/linux-serial-drivers.pdf. Look at  
 line 107 https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3/blob/master/tty/tiny_serial.c. That is what i meant by how uart port gets a reference to tty port.